# Codeigniter - 404 in send data to controller

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, controller, http-status-code-404

**Form**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <?php $attributes = array('class' => 'navbar-form pull-right');
      echo form_open('login/checkLogin', $attributes); ?>
       <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
       <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
       <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

**Contorller**

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller{  

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('templates/menu');
    }
    public function checkLogin(){        
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_verifyUser');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|callback_verifyPassword');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
            $this->load->view('pages/error');
        }else{

        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php

class Login_model extends CI_Model{
    public function login($name, $pass){
        $this->db->select('name, pass');
        $this->db->from('members');
        $this->db->where('name', $name);
        $this->db->where('pass', $pass);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Structure**

application

- controllers

  - login.php
- views

  - templates

    - menu.php

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

My form is located in menu.php, when i push submit return 404
If needed more info please ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution:

**routes.php**

```
$route['templates/menu'] = 'login/checkLogin';
```

**menu.php**

```
echo form_open('templates/menu', $attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

check your **.htaccess** & **php.ini** files. Look at your **mod_rewrite**.. Make sure those are configured correctly and that you are not 404 accidentally on extensions.

Also try instead of

```
 if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $this->load->view('pages/error');
    }
```

try

```
 if(!$this->form_validation->run()){
 $this->load->view('pages/error');
}
```

Comment: I added my. htaccess is located in the root of the project

Comment: try this
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
 
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] 
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
     </IfModule>
     <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 
        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 
    </IfModule>

Comment: My .htacces must be at the root of the project or the server?

Comment: root of project where index.php is

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled using `phpinfo();` in some view, then use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```